# How to disable WordPress .htaccess catch-all?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to `.htaccess` and I have below code in my file;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Currently WordPress handles all the requests. I've updated my site recently and now I want to add few more rules to the `.htaccess`.

How can I restrict WordPress to handle only requests that starts with `/blog/`?

Also I want to add additional rules to `ReWrite` requests to `/cars` to `/index.php/site/cars`

Comment: Why you dont move the wordpress in `blog` directory ?

Comment: @SpartakusMd it's already in the `blog` directory

Comment: Your .htaccess file should be located in the wordpress directory. Well try `RewriteRule /blog/(.*) /blog/index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to my lack of knowledge how `.htaccess` works. I've fixed the issue by moving the `.htaccess` for the `wordpress` to the `/blog` directory and creating a new `.htaccess` with required rules in the `/`.